# Use Regex in C# to remove the word hyperlink and the url from the body of an Outlook email

Tags: c#, regex, outlook

I need to use Regex to remove the word HYPERLINK "http://someUrl.com" from the body of an email that I have stored in a string called body.

Outlook emails always contain the word HYPERLINK (upper case) , a space and two quotes encasing the various link. I'm thinking I can key on the uppercase word - HYPERLINK and the trailing quote - " to remove the links.

Here's the code I have to remove the word HYPERLINK-

```
        Regex regx = new Regex(@"\bHYPERLINK\b");
        body = regx.Replace(body, "");
```

I just can't find a good regex example to remove the wildcards in between HYPERLINK and the trailing quote.

Comment: an example of input and output?

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/327083

Comment: an example of the input would be HYPERLINK "http://someUrl.com" and the output would be nothing. I think that's what you're asking. Thanks!

Comment: That said, it sounds like you're trying to solve the problem of removing or disabling links in your outlook clients' email.  There *are* better ways to do this - you might ask that question instead.

Comment: I'm trying to use the System.Speech.Synthesis; namespace to read back the email to the user with an Outlook plugin. Reading back an email sounds terrible when you include all those URL's,

Comment: @KevinMoore Well, your example isn't "outlook" format - that's RTF.  Take your mail message, set the `.BodyFormat` to plain text, and you're done.  You'll have to remove all of the other RTF formatting marks anyway if you're trying to use speech to read it... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.bodyformat.aspx

Comment: @J... You are correct. This is the best approach rather then using Regex but I'll still need to use regex to clean up any remaining URL's. I just added this -                             ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)mailItem).BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain;
body = mailItem.Body;  to convert the body if anyone stumbles on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this with regex, you need to use capture groups:

```
static string FixHyperlinks(string source)
{
    const string pattern = "HYPERLINK \"([^\"]+)\"";

    return Regex.Replace(source, pattern, m => m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

The pattern matches the entire wrapped URL, but you use a group to isolate the core URL, and then replace the original entire match with just the group values.

Edit:

From reading the comments on your question above, if you want to remove the URL completely, and not just the HYPERLINK "" wrapper, you can just do a replace on the entire matches:

```
static string FixHyperlinks(string source)
{
    const string pattern = "HYPERLINK \"([^\"]+)\"";

    return Regex.Replace(source, pattern, "");
}
```

Comment: Hi Drunken Code Monkey, cool name! You're second edit is very close to what I need but some of the needed text seems to disappear. When I feed in this string for example - string body = @"blah blah blah HYPERLINK ""http://design.1105media.com/sitecore/components/wireframes/gig/martin/temporary/wtnewsletter/wt_redesign-final.jpg"" blah blah blah HYPERLINK ""http://www.idgconnect-resources.com/rt.asp?I=67B29X45A8X7&L=1958441"" blah blah blah"; it outputs 6 blah's and not 9. Is there a way to get all 9?

Comment: so it looks like the middle three blah's are missing in the string above. Thanks for your fantastic example!

Comment: I have edited the pattern above, it should now function correctly in both situations.